# Disable power button in android didn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am developing an Android application for the deaf using the accessibility service

The problem is that deaf people do not need a power button because they will use another device

I tried to call this code

```
val commandLine = "input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine)
```

And it didn't work.

Moreover, the device didn't hook the power button press

I may use the `GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN`, but only supported from API 28, but a minimum of 21 is needed

Getting the root and changing the system settings is not a good choice, because not for developers, the root can break the security

Tested on these devices:

- Samsung S8+ API 29
- PIXEL 2 API 28
- PIXEL 2 API 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ... doesn't works according to user privacy :)